# Passing void(*) in C++

Tags: c++

I have a std::map which I'm trying to store void pointers for the values. The problem is, most of the pointer I'm trying to store are methods in a class and have different amount of params. I know for the params I can use a va list so thats not too much of a problem, the problem would be the actual pointer itself.

This is what I have:

```
class A 
{
public:
  A();
  void methodA(...);
};
class B
{
public:
  B();
  void methodB(...);
};
void method_no_class(...) { }

std::map<int, void(*)(...)> my_map;

my_map[0] = &method_no_class;
B* cb = new B();
my_map[1] = &cb->methodB; // will return error
```

Comment: take a look at boost::bind and boost::function

Comment: @Brian: Make that an answer for a +1.

Comment: The only time void* should be used is in function parameters whose data type is unknown at compile time. Otherwise always use the correct data type even if that type may change at runtime. You can't do anything with a void* pointer except (1) pass it to another function, or (2) typecast it to another data type. So why cause yourself a lot of grief over typecasting and associated problems?

Comment: Reconsider your design. Does it really make sense storing those pointers in the same map? How do you intend to do it? You will need to cast manually, knowing the specific types... using varargs defies all type safety mechanisms in the language...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this information my help you:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1

Pointer to method is of different type than pointer to function. If you want to store them both in single collection you have to do manual casts.

Comment: Not even manual casts help. Pointers to member can not be converted safely to void* and back. See section 4.11 in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The clean OO way would be to define a command interface. The interface would take an instance (of `A` or `B`) and all parameters. In the `invoke()` method, it would call the method of the instance.

You could then use a map of these command interfaces (just define a common subclass for them which defines the abstract `invoke()` method). The compiler would check all types and arguments for you, and you wouldn't have to use varargs.

Answer (score 0):

You should functionoids here. They can be used as a flexible and type safe replacement for function pointers with different signatures. A abstract base class is needed. It contains the actual function invocation with the common parameters, if there are any.

```
class Functioniod: public YourClass {
    virtual void execute(char d, common_parameters,...) = 0
}
```

For every function you want to use, you create a derived class. The constructor contains the function-specific parameters, and the execute() function the actual call. This execute function is later called instead of the function pointer. It needs to have the same signature in every functionoid. It could call something different in any other class too, of course.

```
class FuncA: public Functionoid {
    FuncA(int _a, float _b, string _c, function-specific-parameters...) {
        a = _a; b = _b; c = _c; 
    }
    void execute(char d, common-parameters,...) {
        call-to-member(d, a, b, c);
    }

    int a;
    float b;
    string c;
}
```

Now if you want to use this as a replacement for your member function pointer, you would do:

```
std::map<int, *Functionoid> my_map;

my_map[0] = new FuncA(someInt, someFloat, someString);
my_map[1] = new FuncB(some-other-parameters...);
```

and execute them with

```
my_map[0]->execute(common-parm);
my_map[1]->execute(common-parm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Kamil Szot's answer, the C++ FAQ (and the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309831)) is an excellent reference to the murky depths of C++ and object oriented programming in general. Section 33 addresses specifically the problem you are having:

> In C++, member functions have an implicit parameter which points to the object (the this pointer inside the member function). Normal C functions can be thought of as having a different calling convention from member functions, so the types of their pointers (pointer-to-member-function vs. pointer-to-function) are different and incompatible.

Of course, the [answer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.7) to your question is somewhat lacking in details.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at method operaters ->*, ::*, and their friends. I'll try to find a better link but start [here](http://sexy.w-uh.com/articles/040617-C++_method_pointer.html).

UPDATE: hopefully [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) is a better article for method pointers and operators.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example code to get you started. Haven't compiled it, so might require some tuning.

```
#define func(Instance,Method,Class) \
  (__int64(Instance)<<32 + __int64(&Class::Method))

#define invoke(Func,Method,Class) \
  invoke1(Func,(Class*)0)->*invoke2(Func,&Class::Method)

template<class Class>
Class* invoke1(__int64 Func,Class*)
{
  return (Class*)(int)(Func>>32);
}

template<class Method>
Method invoke2(__int64 Func,Method)
{
  return (Method)(int)Func;
}

------------ USAGE ------------
class B
{
  void methodB(int a,float b){}
};
std::map<int, __int64> my_map;

my_map[0] = func(cb,methodB,B);
invoke(my_map[0],methodB,B)(1,2.f);
```

Comment: Aside from being obvoisly non-portable, this implementation also expects that pointer-to-method size is 32 bits on 32-bit platform. This is absolutely unrealistic. On most implemnentations, pointer-to-method size is always greater that the "ordinary" pointer size (i.e. greater than 32 bits), meaning that the above simply can't work.

Comment: Only when using multiple inheritance and some special compiler pragmas I managed to get 64bit member pointers on 32bit system. On 64bit system you should of course use different implementation. This kind of low-level stuff always requires multiple implementations to be portable. I would much rather have twenty tiny "func_xxx.h" headers than one bloted one.

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to know whether a given class will be used in multible inheritance environment or not (in one of its child classes). For this reason, the implementation has to assume the worst, i.e. it has to assume that the class *is* used with multiple inheritance. For example, VC6 didn't make that assumption by default, and as a result of that perfectly legal code did not work properly.

Comment: Of course you are right. Usually it's just pretty common that code using function pointers won't need multiple inheritance :) Also chances are this code will be pretty experimental. Why spend all that time on learning libraries like boost::function (whose contents is like a black-box for most users) or implementing your own super generic function pointer class if it all could be for nothing. Just remember yagni principle...